# Unable to add svg icon to CardHeader in Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using materi-ui version V0.18.7.

I am trying to add Edit svg icon to CardHeader but it is not appearing. I tried to figure out why it is not appearing but no luck.

```
import {Card, CardActions, CardHeader, CardMedia, CardTitle, CardText} from 'material-ui/Card';
import Edit from 'material-ui/svg-icons/Editor/mode-edit';

<Card>
                     <CardHeader
                          title="Without Avatar"
                          subtitle="Subtitle"
                          openIcon={<Edit />}
                        />

                    <CardText>
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                      Donec mattis pretium massa. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nulla facilisi.
                      Donec vulputate interdum sollicitudin. Nunc lacinia auctor quam sed pellentesque.
                      Aliquam dui mauris, mattis quis lacus id, pellentesque lobortis odio.
                    </CardText>


                  </Card>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import Edit from 'material-ui/svg-icons/editor/mode-edit';
...
<CardHeader
  title="Without Avatar"
  subtitle="Subtitle"
  actAsExpander={true}
  showExpandableButton={true}
  openIcon={<Edit />}
  closeIcon={<Edit />}
/>
...
<CardText expandable={true}>
```